# How to apply threadpool in my code?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool

I coded with Multithreading and It gives Out of Memory errors.
In my personal opinion, it needs to be with thread control(thread pool I suppose).
I was trying to apply thread pool by myself but, I'm stuck with it.
Please I need your kind help(want to make thread with thread pool).

Here is my thread part

```
public Thread CountThread = new Thread() { //Multi Threads begin

  public void run() { //do some work
      counConv();
      cm.readMaleDic(); //method1
      cm.runMatcher(); //method2
      cm.readFemaleDic(); //method3
      cm.runFemaleMatcher(); //method4
      cm.readAgeDic(); //method5
      cm.runAgeMatcher(); //final method
    }
  }; // thread ends
```

and this gives begin signal (int i = at least 100)

```
for (int i = 0; i < dbDescription.length; i++)  { //at least 100 times
      countCon conC = new countCon(); // don't worry about it
      conC.setName(dbDescription[i]); // don't worry about this set method
      conC.CountThread.start(); //thread starts but this gives out of Memory error. 
    }
```

I know using multi thread is not that easy and simple. but to make my code effectively within limited time, the thread pool is required.

Comment: Have you tried [this tutorial](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-util-concurrent/executorservice.html)?

Comment: From the tutorial try ExecutorService which will give you a ready made thread pool ...for starters give no of threads in pool as 10 and feed your tasks to it.